# Need help with remote SQL server. some to do with Azure Portal

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, remote-server

I was supposed to set up a localhost for a user. But it turned out that the website is on an SQL server and not MySQL.

I installed wamp and the website runs fine. But wherever there is a database connection, it tries to connect to the remote server, which doesn't give access. I have some visual studio and configuration files and what not. And I am clueless about what to do.

The website on the localhost tries to connect to the remote server, but i get this message:
"Could not connect. Array ([0] = ... Login failed for user '####'... cannot open server '########' requested by client. client with ##### IP is not allowed to access this server. To enable access, use the SQL Azure Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on master database..

I also have this bit of code in the connection file, that i think shows that the database is hosted on this website:

$srver = "http://########.cloudapp.net/";

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure SQL Azure, you can specify what the allowed IP addresses are. As the error message indicates, the requesting IP is not authorized to access that database.

- [How to: Configure the SQL Azure Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621783.aspx)
- [SQL Azure Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621782.aspx)

Comment: if you find yourself needing to change your Firewall settings a lot, you might want to check out my answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8595035/333730] which allows you to change firewall rules with Powershell.