# Azure - Connect to SQL Server from my local machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, networking

I'd like to check what/how do I set to allow SQL Server being installed in Microsoft Windows Azure to be able to be connected from my local/domain machines?

TQ

Comment: Are you talking about Azure SQL Database or SQL Server installed in VM?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075686/azure-database-connection-error/24075945#24075945

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Access your Azure SQL database from your local machine?

You need to add the IP-address of your local machine to the allowed addresses that can access the database.
You can do this in the azure management portal:

[image]

Sorry my screenshot is in German, but the link should be at the same Position.
It should be called 'Manage allowed IP-addresses' or something similar in English. There you can add the IP-address of your local machine. After that you can access the database from that computer.

Comment: Added the same answer in English version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075686/azure-database-connection-error/24075945#24075945