# Azure SQL database - login failed

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have two web apps in azure plus one SQL database. One of them connects to the db withouth any problem. However the other web app isn't able to connect. I get the error:

```
Login failed for user 'xxxxxx'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'a632c957-78dc-4f13-b07f-ff646b04895c'.
```

I already copied and pasted the connection string from the working web app to the other one with no luck.

Is there any configuration to maybe "allow connections" from a specific web app?

Thanks

Comment: To troubleshoot, please check your firewall settings of the server/database and also please attempt to connect to the database using SSMS or SQL with the same credentials.

Comment: Seems like  your second web app's IP is not added to Firewall.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075686/azure-database-connection-error/24075945#24075945