# SqlErrorNumber=40532 Unable to login to Azure SQL DB​ (or connect linked service)

Tags: database, azure, azure-data-factory, firewall

I keep getting the below error when im trying to create a linked service for my azure sql instance for a quick etl project. I have added my IP address to my firewall  but i don't see a way to add a rule for port 1433.

This is how my firewall is currently setup:

[image]

Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support.

Server: 'server.database.windows.net', Database: 'Database1', User: 'email.onmicrosoft.com'.

Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.

Cannot open server "acc.onmicrosoft.com" requested by the login. The login failed., SqlErrorNumber=40532,Class=20,State=1,
Activity ID: 861b100a-9ec6-46ae-929b-7f730319a741.

please help - I need to connect to the SQL DB i created in my resource group (azure newbie)
well my storage account is linking fine but by SQL data base is not:

[image]

[image]

Comment: which authentication you are using to connect to database?

Comment: @SeekQuil75 , Please post your linked service configuration. The error seems more a permissions issue then a firewall issue.

Comment: Using both AD user and SQL authentication

Comment: I just added them to the original thread - I'm actually using the azure subscription on the "Account Selection Method"

Comment: ...from Azure subscription  - AD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543653/windows-azure-client-with-ip-address-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx-is-not-allowed-to-access-t?rq=2